# How to implement custom Video Recorder App in Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying make custom video recorder app , in which having recording button , flash and also having timer .(See in below pic)

I don't want any camera feature in that , screen contain only video recording features !

I am looking for suggestions or reference so that i can achieve!

[image]

**Note :** From last 24 hours i am trying various library and links but its won't work for me because some posts are 4 or 6 years old and they are having many deprecated methods

**What I Tried**

Camera kit:- https://github.com/CameraKit/camerakit-android (i cant find any video recording feature in this)

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaRecorder

https://github.com/CrazyOrr/FFmpegRecorder

[How to build a custom camera recorder app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154694/how-to-build-a-custom-camera-recorder-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I record a Video in my Android App.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-record-a-video-in-my-android-app)

Comment: @leonardkraemer  i already tried most of example from given link, it cant have flash feature and most of example crashed .

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @HB. I found some code, I will post soon!

Comment: Thanks, I'm also looking for basic video recording.

Comment: Hi all, I felt the documentation here was enough to get me started https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera#custom-camera, what issues are you experiencing specifically ?

Comment: Your solution is here try with this one [Custom video recorder app Android](https://findnerd.com/list/view/How-to-create-custom-video-camera-/2957) in this application, you will get the features like flash & video recording timer also you will get some more features like changing the camera from front to rear and also saving video to your local storage

Comment: Yeah this would be helpful blog for this problem